# Mounting vmfs5 under linux?

Tags: linux, vmware-esxi, cluster, vmfs

Can anyone tell me if there is a safe (i.e. data won't be corrupted) a VMFS 5 filesystem under linux, where the VMFS 5 filesystem is already mounted by several ESXi hosts in a vSphere cluster?

Comment: I am wanting to copy files without adding additional CPU/IO load to the ESXi hosts.

Answer (score 2):

Why are you interested in doing this? *e.g. What problem are you solving?*

The safety aspect depends entirely upon what you're doing. If you simply need access to your datastores, you can do so via SSH/SCP, FTP... Maybe even NFS (if using NAS storage for VMWare). Obviously read-only would be non-destructive in any case.

There's the old [VMFS driver](http://code.google.com/p/vmfs/) for Linux, but that only supports older VMFS-3 and is read-only. I'm not sure you even have an option for VMFS-5 without using third-party recovery forensics tools like [UFS Explorer](http://www.ufsexplorer.com/download_stdr.php).